# Remove index.html from URL in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am using Angular JS for my Front End, Java is the Service layer.

I am trying to remove the index.html from my url.

Now : `http://localhost:3000/Myapp/index.html#!/login`

I want look like : `http://localhost:3000/Myapp/client1#!/login`

I tried : `$locationProvider.hashPrefix();`but it is not working.

Could you please some one suggest how to make it work.

Thanks in advance !

`

Answer (score -1):

This is something that needs to be configured on the server. You would need to configure your server to serve the index.html file on the route `Myapp/client1`

Comment: could you please suggest what are changes need to add server side, thanks for great answer @mike

Comment: I don't know what server you are using, you should look at the documentation for whatever it is

Answer (score -1):

you could activate the HTML5 mode for [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

```
angular.module('yourApp',[]).config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
    ...
});
```

But this would simply replace `index.html` with nothing. If you want to be replaced by `client1` you have to do it on your server, for example with `mod_rewrite` in your .htaccess, if you are using apache

Comment: Hi @chresse, I tried this one, but it is not working, Do you have any other solution too

Comment: @Coder: what exactly did you try? which error did you receive?

Comment: Hi @Chresse, I am getting Error like this: Uncaught Error: `[$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/$location/nobase`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this approach could help:

Add $locationProvider.hashPrefix();, which removes index.html in your URL, in your app.js config. Don't forget to add the new dependency. After that your app.js could look similar to this:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute'
])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix(); // Removes index.html in URL

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/someroute'});
}]);
```

Comment: Is it remove only index.html or file name anything it will remove, like my start file name is: myapp.html  (example) @Suneet Bansal

Comment: Hi @Sunnet Bansal, I tried with your solution, but is it not loading all js files and css files, becasue all my css files and js  files.